# LWC create record - getting 'undefined' for record.id in 'then'

Tags: lightning-web-components, create-records

I'm successfully creating a new record from my LWC, but I can't seem to access the content of the new record in the 'then' part of the code. I would like to display the Name of new record (which is an auto-generated number) as part of the success message. What am I missing? I thought the newly created record was accessable?

```
createRecord(recordInput)
.then(cert => {
    alert('certificate: ' + cert);
    this.certref = cert.Name;
    alert('certificate Id + Name : ' + cert.Id + ' ' + cert.Name);
    this.dispatchEvent(
        new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Success',
            message: 'Certificate created - Ref No: ' + this.certref,
            variant: 'success',
        }),
    );
})
```

The first alert:

[image]

The second alert:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `cert.id` and/or `cert.name` (lowercase field names)? The examples I see in the docs seems to access the field names in lowercase.

Comment: Hey that works for the id, which it now returns, but not the name. Does this mean the name is not accessible?

Comment: Do you have the `name` field set in `fields` attribute for `createRecord`?

Comment: No I didn't, so I added it but it's not making a difference. It still comes back as undefined. It is an Auto Number so it's generated on creation.

Comment: you may can try to use a @wire getRecord using the returned Id to get the Name of the created record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at [Create a Record](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_resources_records_create.htm) documentation, the field's values are returned in the `fields` attribute and that every field in that map itself is a JSON string.

With a working example as on the [LWC docs for Create Records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_salesforce_write), I could see that every field returned in the `fields` attribute have two attributes namely `displayValue` and `value` (print from the console for this test)

[image]

So to get the `Name` field's value, I had to parse the Proxy object `account` that was returned from server as JSON, and then get the `Name` field's value.

```
createRecord(recordInput)
        .then(account => {
            ...
            const retAccount = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(account));
            console.log(retAccount.fields.Name.value); // this is the field's value
            ...
)
```

In your case, you will need to do the same thing, just by replacing the `account` in the above example with your attribute name `cert` should yield the result.

Comment: Yes, it all works now - great thanks!